# How to Centre Glyphicon Vertically In Bootstrap Button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place a glyphicon inside a bootstrap button. When I reduce the width/height of the button, the glyphicon no longer stays centered, vertically or horizontally. I can fix the horizontal position using position:relative.

However, I can't figure out how to fix it's vertical positioning.

Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-podcast-btn">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-center"></span>
</button>
```

And here is what the CSS looks like:

```
.add-podcast-btn {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.glyphicon-center {
  position: relative;
  right: 4.5px;
}
```

I've included a PLNKR to show whats going on:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5TAvWpZ3l9ntKpJCJZAA

Comment: Bootstrap provides classes that alter the size of the buttons, [see the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-sizing). Have you tried them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/06lYcyqGYn5IC6U9N3uR?p=preview

```
.add-podcast-btn {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.glyphicon-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the predefined bootstrap button sizes you won't need to manually adjust the height of the buttons.

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default add-podcast-btn">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-center"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-podcast-btn">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-center"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default add-podcast-btn">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-center"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default add-podcast-btn">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-center"></span>
</button>

<br/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default add-podcast-btn">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-center"></span> Add podcast
</button>

<br/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-podcast-btn">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-center"></span> Add podcast
</button>

<br/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default add-podcast-btn">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-center"></span> Add podcast
</button>

<br/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default add-podcast-btn">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-center"></span> Add podcast
</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately when you use the default styles the glyphicons don't look horizontally centered. If you look closely you can tell, especially when looking at the icon-only `btn-xs` and `btn-sm`.

Answer (score 0):

Try just this line.

```
<button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button>
```